# Java, why do my lines always white out in BlueJ?

Tags: java, bluej, visual-glitch

While typing my code out, some lines automatically get spaced out, and whenever I try to click or type something, more lines disappear in the process, therefore making me delete the class itself.
I have encountered this same issue on another system.

I cannot even Ctrl+A my code, help!

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: which ide are you using ? or is it some text editor ?

Comment: I use BlueJ. This happens occasionally.

Comment: Downvoters should comment to explain the downvotes. This appears to be a question about "software tools commonly used by programmers" and so is arguably on-topic. It's a _bit_ unclear, but comments are the way to correct that, not downvotes. Maybe people are downvoting because they've never heard of BlueJ?

Comment: I completely agree. At least, I should be told WHY the question deserved a downvote, not be left unanswered. After all, the end motive of all of us is to learn and to help others learn. We should be completely open to criticism and corrections, rather than ending up with deleted questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The BlueJ FAQ mentions possible display artifacts on Windows:

> **There are visual artifacts on the BlueJ windows (black areas,
>   distorted text, etc) in Windows**
>
> Visual artifacts - black areas,
>   distorted or missing text, etc - are usually a result of either a
>   display driver bug or a Java bug. Try updating your display drivers
>   (see here for Windows 7) or disabling graphics acceleration (see
>   here).

https://bluej.org/faq.html#win_visual_artifcats

It makes several recommendations for how to fix them:

- update display drivers
- update JDK
- change VM args

Read the linked FAQ for instructions.

The release log also tells a similar story, so make sure you've updated BlueJ:

> 4.1.0 23 June 2017
>
> Major fixes:
>
> Fixed: Graphical display bug could cause the Java editor and other
>   windows (e.g. Terminal) to turn white and not redraw correctly.

https://bluej.org/versions.html